# How do I determine that whether roads are one-sided or two-sided in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database i.e., `roads` and `buildings`. The sample scenarios are as:

**Scenario_1:**

[image: Scenario_1]

**Scenario_2**

[image: Scenario_2]

In PostGIS, for each road how can I determine that whether it is one-sided or two sided (depending on building polygons on one or two sides of the road center line)? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.